# Replace values in a large matrix in R to make an identity matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to convert a large sparse matrix (dimension: 4445 x 2621) to an identity matrix. The row and column names are strings. The idea is all the values that are 1 and above should be equal to 1.

Eg:

```
Mat = [5,0,1
       10,11,0
       3,0,0]
```

will become,

```
[1,0,1
 1,1,0
 1,0,0]
```

The code I used is

```
B[B >= 1] = 1
```

I also used the following :

```
B = replace(B,B>=1, 1)
```

and

```
> typeof(B)
[1]"character"
```

I tried changing it as `as.numeric(B)` to convert the character value to numeric, but that just makes it a large numeric. I am certain it is because the values are characters. Kindly point me to the mistake.

Comment: Please include a reproducible example with *valid* syntax.

Comment: if it is *represented* as a sparse matrix (i.e. via `Matrix()` from the `Matrix` package) then something like `M@x[M@x>=1] <- 1` should work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
storage.mode(B) = "numeric"
B[B>=1] = 1
B[B<1] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. This did the job best.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to subset the range to which you wish to assign using the condition "greater than 0", like this:

```
Mat = rbind(c(5,0,1),c(10,11,0),c(3,0,0))
Mat1 <- Mat
Mat1[Mat > 0] <- 1
```

Result:

```
Mat1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    1
[2,]    1    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0
```